# YUV frame scaling in Android

Tags: android, video-streaming

I am developing an application in android that streams the live video from android to pc. I am capturing frame by frame video on `Camera.onPreviewFrame()` and then sending acquired `byte[]` `YUV` data to server using socket.

This method is working fine. Only the problem I am facing is the no. of frames per second. It is now 4-5 fps and I want to achieve 15-16 fps.

To achieve this, I am thinking of compressing this `YUV` data. Currently my app gives me frame of resolution 320 X 240. I want it to scale it down so that I can reduce the no. of bytes to send on the network. Is there any library or algorithm which can do this?

Is there any other way of streaming live video from android phone to pc?

Answer (score 1):

I recommand resizing YUV data. But the MAXIMUM resolution of your phone is better then others.

1. YUV -> anoter Color space ( RGBA, BGRA, ARGB.. etc...)
2. resizing RGBA using openCV or meth...
3. processing
4. resizing (up)